# Is this a correct SPARQL query to select all used classes?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

**Question:** is this a correct query to select all **used** classes which are **mandatory** defined in `<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl>` or am I missing something?

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT  DISTINCT ?class
FROM <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl>
WHERE {
  { ?class a owl:Class } UNION {?class a rdfs:Class} .
  { ?instance a ?class} .
 }
```

Output:

```
1   owl:DatatypeProperty
2   owl:Class
3   owl:ObjectProperty
4   owl:Ontology
5   owl:AnnotationProperty
6   owl:OntologyProperty
```

Comment: it depends on what you mean by "used" - used in RDF triples as type would obviously be only `?instance a ?class` - but declared explicitly and inferred from RDF axiomatic triples, then "no" - domain and range axioms can also use classes, if we go into complex OWL constructs, equivalent classes might be used

Comment: What does "mandatory defined" mean?